# Copying all files of one type from a directory throws a file in use error with Recursion

Tags: java, file, recursion, copy

I am very new to recursion and file manipulation in java and I would like to write a program to copy all of the files of one type in a directory and all of its subdirectories into the directory that the program is located in. However, I keep getting an IOException:
 The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
My recursion code is as follows:

```
private ArrayList<File> addSongList(String dir) {
    ArrayList<File> songsToAdd = new ArrayList<File>();

    File currentFolder = new File(dir);
    File[] files = currentFolder.listFiles();

    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
        if (files[i].getName().contains(".mp3") || files[i].getName().contains(".wma"))
            songsToAdd.add(files[i]);
        else if (files[i].isDirectory())
            songsToAdd.addAll(addSongList(dir + "/" + files[i].getName()));

    return songsToAdd;
}
```

basically it goes through all of the directories and subdirectories in the original dir variable and adds all .mp3 and .wav files to an arraylist (songsToAdd). This method is called here:

```
            ArrayList<File> Songs = addSongList(dir);
            String finalPath = new File("").getAbsolutePath();
            for(int i = 0; i < Songs.size(); i++){
                try {
                    Files.copy(Songs.get(i).toPath(), new File(finalPath).toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
                    System.out.println("Copied " + Songs.get(i).getName() + " to " + finalPath);
                } catch (IOException arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    arg0.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Copy Complete!");
```

by an action listener. I can't figure out why it is throwing this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the name of the song to be copied in the target path like below :

```
ArrayList<File> Songs = addSongList( dir );

for(int i = 0; i < Songs.size(); i++){
   try {
        Path sourcePath = Songs.get(i).toPath();
        Path targetPath = Paths.get(Songs.get(i).getName()).toAbsolutePath();

        Files.copy(sourcePath, targetPath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        System.out.println("Copied " + Songs.get(i).getName() + " to " + targetPath.toString());
        } catch (IOException arg0) {
               // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                arg0.printStackTrace();
            }
}
System.out.println("Copy Complete!");
```

If you look at the documentation for [Files.copy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...)), it says `Copy a file to a target file.` Therefore you need to specify what file? You can also choose a different name for your copied file if you want. like `Path targetPath = Paths.get("Copied_" + Songs.get(i).getName() ).toAbsolutePath()`

Also on a side note, I would suggest in the `addSongList` method, first check if it is a `directory` then else to `getName().contains(...)` like :

```
if ( fileNames[i].isDirectory() )
{
   songsToAdd.addAll(addSongList(dir + "/" + files[i].getName()));
}
else if (files[i].getName().contains(".mp3") || files[i].getName().contains(".wma"))
{
   songsToAdd.add(files[i]);
}
```